# Is passing mutablestate to composable function optimal?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, state-management, composable, mutablestateof

Like this :

```kotlin
@Composable
fun TextEdit(textState: MutableState<String>) {
    val text by textState
    TextField(onValueChange = {
        text = it
    }, value = text)
}
```

Is it optimal for unnecessary recompositions?

Answer (score 1):

That will still trigger unnecessary recompositions, instead try using the concept of **[state hoisting](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state-hoisting)** where your code should be:

```
@Composable
fun TextEdit(textState: String) {
    
    TextField(onValueChange = {
        textState = it
    }, value = textState)
}
```

Here is the **Best Practice** to follow:

> You should hoist UI state to the lowest common ancestor between all
> the composables that read and write it. You should keep state closest
> to where it is consumed. From the state owner, expose to consumers
> immutable state and events to modify the state.
>
> The lowest common ancestor can also be outside of the Composition. For
> example, when hoisting state in a ViewModel because business logic is
> involved.

Comment: Are you sure that it will trigger unnecessary recompositions? How?